# jQuery unbind after first click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

This causes multiple buttons to take action:

```
$(document).on("click", ".file-this-email", fileThisEmail);
```

When `fileThisEmail` runs, I'd like to remove it from ONLY the current one (there are others on the page that still need it):

```
window.fileThisEmail = function(e) {
  console.log('this was clicked');
}
```

I tried `off`, but couldn't seem to get it right. Any ideas?

Comment: how did you try `off()`? like this `$(this).off('click')`?

Comment: Binding to the `document` with a delegate selector like that doesn't bind the handler to the individual elements. The only handler is the one on the `document`, and it is responsible for handling the event on all elements that match the selector. This is called ***"event delegation"***, and it would be a good idea to learn about how it works before using it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. While I understand your point, saying "it would be a good idea to learn about how it works before using it" is exactly the reason forums on the internet get bad raps. If this were the case, no one in technology would ever accomplish anything. They'd be too busy reading documentation. I've used it quite successfully for many years without getting in to this level of detail.

Comment: Sorry, but that's *absolute nonsense*. People who read documentation *accomplish more* because of what they've learned. People who come to SO and ask for solutions without gaining knowledge end up writing bad code and operating without the means to solve simple problems. You say my suggestion to learn it (a very simple concept) gives forums a bad rap, and yet here you are with a problem that would have been obvious had you taken the time to understand these basic concepts.

Comment: Everyone has different approaches for learning.

Comment: Avoiding learning isn't an approach to learning.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm also one of those people that don't read documentation until after it doesn't work, so i can definitely understand where you're coming from. However, in this case I definitely suggest reading further on delegated events.

Comment: @KevinB: But you do ultimately read it when necessary, no?

Comment: @squint I don't think asking a question is avoiding learning. Speaking personally, I find certain documentation easier to understand than others. For instance, I spend most of my days writing Ruby, and as a result, I find Ruby's docs to be approachable. However, I started learning Go a few months back and it was quite the opposite. So while I appreciate documentation and will regularly refer to it, sometimes I find other places easier to learn from. The jquery documentation doesn't do it for me. I find myself going straight to the examples.

Comment: Asking a question isn't avoiding learning. You know I didn't say that. Scoffing at the mere suggestion to understand fundamental concepts most certainly is. I learned Go. Now I'm learning Rust *(because Go is just too limiting)*, and Rust isn't even an officially released language. I'm learning partly by using tuts like [this](http://www.rustforrubyists.com/) and [this](http://rustbyexample.com/), which do help. Naturally questions are a part of learning, but the key is that learning actually take place, especially in languages like Go and Rust where subtle details can make a big difference.

Comment: Totally agree. If I said something to make it seem like I was "scoffing" at the idea of learning fundamentals, I must have mispoke. I apologize that that was the message that came across. I don't use intricacies like this in my daily work enough for it to stick. I've gone back a few times to _really_ try to understand some of this stuff and for one reason or another, it doesn't stick. I wish were the result were different :( It's just a bummer to ask a question and then seemingly get chastized for asking it. While I'm sure that's not what you genuinely meant to do, that's how it came across :/

Comment: Then my apologies. My original comment truly meant merely to convey the message that it's a good idea to learn about event delegation before using it because it's an important fundamental concept to understand.

Comment: No problem at all. Out of curiosity, do you have any favorite resources aside from the docs?

Comment: In all honesty, no. It always depends on the problem at hand. Sometimes standards and specifications are best, sometimes API docs, sometimes user experience conveyed though forums and blogs *(though I take it with a big grain of salt, and usually use them as a starting point to dig deeper into new concepts)*. So other than Google, not really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In this case, you have to make the current element no longer match the `".file-this-email"` selector.

```
$(document).on("click", ".file-this-email", function() {
    console.log('this was clicked');
    $(this).removeClass("file-this-email");
});
```

An alternative would be to add a filter to the selector, with the same concept.

```
$(document).on("click", ".file-this-email:not(.clicked)", function() {
    console.log('this was clicked');
    $(this).addClass("clicked");
});
```

Or, don't use delegation for this particular case. Delegation isn't some new technology that replaces direct binding, it's just another way of binding events. If used correctly, it can make code more efficient. The opposite is true too; if used incorrectly, it can make the code very bloated.

```
$(".file-this-email").on("click", function () {
    console.log("this was clicked");
    $(this).off("click");
});
// or even better (thanks @overachiever):
$(".file-this-email").one("click", function () {
    console.log("this was clicked");
});
```

Comment: the last one with `off` could potentially unbind other click events though, since you do not specify the original callback or namespace

Comment: Very true. .one is the better alternative to the last case

Comment: @sphanley, i intended to use .one, not .on.

Comment: I opted for: `$(document).one("click", ".pipelinedeals-file-this-email", function(e){});` b/c the elements aren't on the page yet when this renders. But the point with `one` is well taken. Thanks!

Comment: I didn't think that was the behavior you were going for, since `$(document).one("click"` will only trigger once per `document`, rather than once per `".pipelinedeals-file-this-email"`

Comment: A [little knowledge](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167061/jquery-unbind-after-first-click/26167214#comment41024914_26167061) is a dangerous thing. I'm guessing he opted to assign a unique class to each button and bind at the `document` level has a hack to "get it to work" as we so often hear. And I'd further bet that he has all events bound at the `document` level. All this because he seems to think that the suggestion to understand basic concepts is bad advice. I hope I'm wrong.

Comment: I don't have all events bound at the `document` level. And I definitely don't think understanding basic concepts is bad advice. Thanks for the helpful feedback.

Comment: Just to follow up, you're right, it was not the behavior I was intending. I used the last snippet in your answer `one` and it worked well. I had to reorg somethings so I could do it where the button was being inserted in to the DOM. It's a little hairy because this is a Chrome used in the Gmail interface so it does require some hoop jumping. But thanks for providing a bunch of great thoughts, which ultimately got me to where I needed to go.

Answer (score 0):

The .one() method is good for this.  http://api.jquery.com/one/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.file-this-email').one('click', fileThisEmail);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that it being bound to the document will cause it to only happen for the first time on that selector.  I edited to fix it.

Comment: oddly... it appears as though that's the solution he went with, but that doesn't seem to be what he asked for. \*confused*

Answer (score 0):

Bind individual handlers to each element like this:

```
$(".file-this-email").one("click",fileThisEmail);
```

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is

```
$(document).on("click", ".file-this-email", fileThisEmail);
```

change this to

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".file-this-email").on("click",fileThisEmail);
  $(".file-this-email").click(function(){
    $(this).off("click",fileThisEmail);
  });
 });
```